# How can i style mobile-jquery's back button?

Tags: jquery, mobile, themes

normally we could specify data-theme = "a" or b or c, etc at any div.
however as "Back" button is auto generated by jQuery mobile, how to specify its theme?

Thanks,
-wan

Comment: Try advices from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666491/image-in-jquery-mobile-back-button-doesnt-appear

Comment: Thanks Londeren for your comment, I appreciate that..

Answer (score 3):

The button style can be changed using the following:

$.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnTheme = "b";

Answer (score 0):

just found out that we could simply put data-theme at header div
however it did not fully work -- (change back to blue always) if you click back button once -- and go back to the same page..

it is an existing bug and the workaround is by removeClass below --- and bind it at pagebeforehide.

jQuery("#page_id_e.g.123').removeClass("ui-btn-active");